# Stream audio over websocket with low latency and no interruption

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, streaming, audio-streaming

I'm working on a project which requires the ability to stream audio from a webpage to other clients. I'm already using websocket and would like to channel the data there.

My current approach uses Media Recorder, but there is a problem with sampling which causes interrupts. It registers 1s audio and then send's it to the server which relays it to other clients. Is there a way to capture a continuous audio stream and transform it to base64?

Maybe if there **is a way to create a base64 audio from MediaStream** without delay it would solve the problem. What do you think?

I would like to keep using websockets, I know there is webrtc.
Have you ever done something like this, is this doable?

```
                                                                --> Device 1
 MediaStream -> MediaRecorder -> base64 -> WebSocket -> Server --> Device ..
                                                                --> Device 18
```

Here a demo of the current approach... you can try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/8qhvrcbz/

```
var sendAudio = function(b64) {
  var message = 'var audio = document.createElement(\'audio\');';
  message += 'audio.src = "' + b64 + '";';
  message += 'audio.play().catch(console.error);';
  eval(message);
  console.log(b64);
}

 navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      audio: true
 }).then(function(stream) {
        setInterval(function() {
            var chunks = [];
            var recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
            recorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
                chunks.push(e.data);
            };
            recorder.onstop = function(e) {
                var audioBlob = new Blob(chunks);
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(audioBlob);
                reader.onloadend = function() {
                    var b64 = reader.result
                    b64 = b64.replace('application/octet-stream', 'audio/mpeg');
                    sendAudio(b64);
                }
            }
            recorder.start();
            setTimeout(function() {
                recorder.stop();
            }, 1050);
        }, 1000);
    });
```

Comment: Sidenote: why use Base64? WebSockets support binary data. Saving encoding/decoding will save both CPU and bandwidth.

Comment: It's easier to test with base64, I tried with binary but there was not so much of improvement

Comment: @Myst I think the problem is with the MediaRecorder not with the data itself, it skips even without involving websockets. Or maybe it's becouse the player delay. I made a fiddle witch is using blob instead of base64 https://jsfiddle.net/StarStep/0cqm56rz/4/

Comment: Why would use you Web Sockets for this?  Use WebRTC, which has a whole stack designed for low latency.  Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I just posted the same answer 2 min ago. But yeah webrtc seems to handle audio better. I would like to use websocket because it was easier to send the data to many clients, offloading the job to the server. With WebRTC we are using way more connections... gonna test it.

Comment: Probably there is a way to make a middleware on the server which will relay the data, for the moment will stick to the foundamentals.

Answer (score 1):

Websocket is not the best. I solved by using WebRTC instead of websocket. 
The solution with websocket was obtained while recording 1050ms instead of 1000, it causes a bit of overlay but still better than hearing blanks.

Answer (score 1):

*Although you have solved this through WebRTC, which is the industry recommended approach, I'd like to share my answer on this.*

The problem here is not *websockets* in general but rather the MediaRecorder API. Instead of using it one can use PCM audio capture and then submit the captured array buffers into a web worker or WASM for encoding to MP3 chunks or similar.

```
const context = new AudioContext();
let leftChannel = [];
let rightChannel = [];
let recordingLength = null;
let bufferSize = 512;
let sampleRate = context.sampleRate;

const audioSource = context.createMediaStreamSource(audioStream);
const scriptNode = context.createScriptProcessor(bufferSize, 1, 1);

audioSource.connect(scriptNode);
scriptNode.connect(context.destination);
scriptNode.onaudioprocess = function(e) {
    // Do something with the data, e.g. convert it to WAV or MP3
};
```

Based on my experiments this would give you "real-time" audio. My theory with the MediaRecorder API is that it does some buffering first before emitting out anything that causes the observable delay.